# How do I continue to process a file despite a UnicodeDecodeError error?

Tags: python, file-io

I got about 10,000 files with a total of about 50 million records in them. The files come from different sources. I need to read and process all rows in these files. The files are expected to be in **ASCII** but given the different processing environments used in creating the files, very many files break that format.

When processing, I am often getting codec errors e.g.

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 106: character maps to <undefined>`.

Another error would be

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 0: invalid start byte`

If I change the codec format, the file is processed but then a few files later yet another file throws a different codec error.

Also, the files don't always fail at the beginning of the file. A file can be processed until 50,000 records only for it to fail. For the sake of leaving out as little data as possible -i.e. not just quitting on the whole file coz I hit a codec error-, how should I format my script so that:

1. It tries to run a file that has failed with as many formats
   possible/available? *Side note: Please give a list of the common
   file formats if you can*.
2. To continue processing the file even when
       a specific row of data cannot be processed by any of the formats
       specified in 1 above?
3. To do all this in a graceful and pythonic way.

Here was my original code for processing the file

```
with codecs.open(file_path, encoding="utf8") as f:
    for file in f:
        `some long code to read the file and dump it to database`
```

After some Googling am now at the following code which to me is not very elegant as I can't possible repeat all the code for all the different file formats possible:

```
 codec_option = 0
 while True:
            try:
                if codec_option == 0:
                    with codecs.open(file_path, encoding="utf8") as f:
                        for line in f:
                            `some long code to read the file and dump it to database. when done, break`
                elif codec_option == 1:
                    with codecs.open(file_path, encoding="cp1252") as f:
                        for line in f:
                            `some long code to read the file and dump it to database. when done, break`

            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                codec_option += 1
                continue
                return entry_counter
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could try guessing the encoding of the file using [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet).

Comment: to make sure: do you understand the difference between [ascii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (7-bit character encoding) and ["ansi, extended ascii"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) (don't use that term).

Comment: Have you tried `encoding='ascii', errors='ignore'` or other error handlers?

Comment: Even enumerating all available character encodings one by one does not guarantee that no error happens. Even if there is no error; it does not mean that the result is not garbage. It is upto to you for your particular specific case to decide what is sensible to do: delete, replace, decode using arbitrary encoding, pass bytes as is.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I gave up and went with your suggestion and added `errors=ignore` and it replaced/got-rid-of the `odd/bad` characters and proceeded with the good ones. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the files are encoded in proper way, then you will have to decode the `BOM (Byte order marker)` first to figure out the encoding.

You can use [codec](http://pymotw.com/2/codecs/) module. It can detect the BOM and decode the files accordingly.